# conditional summarising of reoccuring variables

Tags: r

I have the following, simplified data frame.

```
obj <- data.frame (id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
Date = c("1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1991-01", "1991-02", "1991-03", "1991-04", "1991-01", "1991-02", "1991-03", "1991-04"),
                   degree = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
)
```

Note that my real ID's are named something like 2.01811e+13

What I would like to do is the following:

- I would like to create a new column which should be 1 for a date where degree turns to 2 and the previous observation is 1 but it should just hold if variable ID remains the same.
- For every degree = 1 the new column should be zero.
- For any degree = 0 the new column should take NA.
- For any other degree = 2 (so if the previous degree of the same id observation was not 1) the new column should be NA as well.
  Note that consecutive id observations might overlap across years in the real sample, e.g. an ID ranging from 1990-11, 1990-12, 1991-01, 1991-02.

it should look like this,

```
id date    degree new_col 
1   1990-01   1     0
1   1990-02   1     0 
1   1990-03   1     0
1   1990-04   2     1
2   1990-01   1     0
2   1990-02   1     0
2   1990-03   0     NA
2   1990-04   1     0
1   1991-01   2     NA
1   1991-02   2     NA
1   1991-03   2     NA
1   1991-04   2     NA
2   1991-01   1     0
2   1991-02   1     0
2   1991-03   2     1
2   1991-04   2     0
```

I guess the way to do it is to write a for loop for each ID

```
case_when(degree == 2 & lag(degree) == 1 ~ 1,
                                degree == 1 ~ 0,
                                T ~ NA_real_))
```

But I'm not sure how to exactly incorporate the code above into a loop dependent on ID.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please clarify the statement "but it should just hold if variable ID remains the same." in your first bullet point?

Comment: Of course!  Each ID appears two times in my whole data set, always for 4 consecutive times. If variable degree changes from 1 to 2 and the variable ID is for both the same, new_col should take the value 1. On the other hand, if variable degree changes from 1 (where ID=1) to 2 (where ID=2) new_col should be NA. 
Best regards1

Comment: OK this is really helpful: have updated answer to reflect this logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close.  Using `dplyr` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

obj %>% 
  mutate(new_col= case_when(degree == 2 & lag(degree) == 1 & id == lag(id) ~ 1,
                            degree == 2  & lag(degree) == 1  & id == 2 & lag(id) == 1 ~ 0,
                            degree == 1 ~ 0,
                            T ~ NA_real_)) 
#>    id    Date degree new_col
#> 1   1 1990-01      1       0
#> 2   1 1990-02      1       0
#> 3   1 1990-03      1       0
#> 4   1 1990-04      2       1
#> 5   2 1990-01      1       0
#> 6   2 1990-02      1       0
#> 7   2 1990-03      0      NA
#> 8   2 1990-04      1       0
#> 9   1 1991-01      2      NA
#> 10  1 1991-02      2      NA
#> 11  1 1991-03      2      NA
#> 12  1 1991-04      2      NA
#> 13  2 1991-01      1       0
#> 14  2 1991-02      1       0
#> 15  2 1991-03      2       1
#> 16  2 1991-04      2      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>